# Is it possible to put a label into an actionColumn?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Currently it seems I can just add buttons.
Anyway I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
a label |button|
```

would it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is using a **container**.

here is the example :

```
var container = {
xtype  : 'container',
layout : 'hbox',
style  : 'margin-bottom: 5px;',
items  : [
   {
      xtype: 'label',
     text: 'a Label',
    },
    {
        xtype : 'container',
        width : 85,
        items : {
            xtype : "button",
            text  : "button",
            width : 70              
        }
    }       
]};
```

hope this work.